# Automatically reverse an edit to a google sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have seen before a google script that, in onEdit(e), automatically reversed whatever edit was made to a given sheet cell. I'd like some code for that!

Thanks for whatever help you can provide.

Comment: Does it just clear the cell back to blank, or are the cells filled with data and any changes get reverted?

Comment: Also can you provide any code that you have tried?

Comment: Hi Ruan - Thanks for asking. I haven't tried any code yet because I've seen it somewhere before. Result I'm looking for: When some users try to update a cell, I want to simply put back into the cell whatever was just in it before the edit, whether null or content. The background is that google permissions and access rules don't provide sufficient control over my work flows. I need to code so that some users CAN edit whereas other user changes are rejected. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: In sheets you can protect a range and specify specific people who may edit that range, while others will only be able to view it. `Select range > Right click > Protect range > Set permission > Restrict who can edit this range > custom`.  
If that is not good enough then you will want to look at storing either a snapshot of the sheet or store edits and revert back as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But this needs to be more automated than manual selections allow. Also, managing nuanced user access in code, when the access changes during workflow, doesn't work well because every user has to give permission to the document to run the code. Which is a pain when you've got lots of unskilled users. SO ,.. I need to manage this WITHIN script behaviors that don't trigger permission/access requirements. The best way to do that is to use internal criteria in the document to control when edits are permitted and when they are reversed. Hence. the need to reverse edits.

Comment: You mentioned `onEdit(e)`. I'm pretty sure this will trigger permission requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to revert the current edit that was made. Namely, change the new value with the value that was before the edit was made.

- You want to do that for a specific cell and sheet.

### Solution:

In the following script choose the sheet name and the cell reference and after you edit that particular cell (A1 in Sheet1 in the example), the old value will be retrieved back to the cell.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // choose the name of the Sheet
  const cell = "A1"; // choose the cell
  const rng = e.range;
  if(rng.getA1Notation() == cell && rng.getSheet().getName() == sheetName){
    rng.setValue(e.oldValue); 
  }
}
```

**Illustration:**

Every edit on cell A1 is reversed.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marios, this is unrelated to the question above, but how do you capture your screen and add it as GIF in stackoverflow? I always wonder how. Is there any way of doing it without adding an extension/installing apps?

Comment: Hi @NaziA thanks for your comment. I am using a very light software  : https://licecap.en.softonic.com/ but maybe there are better options .. I didn't search that much.

Comment: I see. Everything I found on the internet points to an external software/extension and isn't viable with me. Thanks @Marios.